# How can I replace very small scientific form of numbers in output with 0.0?

Tags: output-formatting

How cam I get rid of very small scientific form numbers in my output, replacing them with zero? (eg: 2.27682*10^-18 --> 0.0)

Comment: Can you give an example input and your expected output?

Comment: 2.27682*10^-18    ---->     0.0

Comment: That's still a bit ambiguous. `Round[2.27682*10^-18] = 0`

Comment: Round just returns the integer part!

Comment: It fits your example. Your intention here is very unclear.

Comment: I agree...@richard could you be more specific? For example, `Chop` also does the work. Is it what you want?

Comment: @LeoFang, thanks Chop seems good, sorry for being unclear